# iCloud Entitlements missing in Provisioning Profile

Tags: ios, xcode, icloud, provisioning-profile, entitlements

I am using XCode 8.1 and have enabled iCloud documents capability in the capabilities tab of the target. I can see the following entries getting generated in the Entitlements file:

- iCloud Container Identifiers
- iCloud Services
- Ubiquity Container Identifiers

I have also enabled iCloud in the provisioning profile. But still I'm getting issues that these 3 entitlements are missing in the profile.

If I select “Automatically Manage Signing option” in XCode, then I get the following error:

Your account does not have sufficient permissions to modify containers.

Could anybody please let me know if i am missing something here?

Comment: Stupid question, but are you registered Apple Developer? You need to be registered to use/access iCloudKit.

Comment: Yes, I'm a registered apple developer.